# Am I right or are they?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, singular

Shouldn't it be

> The Albiceleste captain looked embarrassed when he was awarded the
>   Golden Ball as the tournament's best player after his country **was**
>   beaten 1-0 in the final by Germany.

instead of

> The Albiceleste captain looked embarrassed when he was awarded the
>   Golden Ball as the tournament's best player after his country **were**
>   beaten 1-0 in the final by Germany.

which is how it is in this [link](http://www.espnfc.com/real-madrid/story/2009826/cristiano-ronaldo-keeping-quiet-over-lionel-messis-world-cup-award)

Answer (score 2):

In American English, collective nouns are treated as singular; in British English, as plurals.

> American: The Acme Widgets company is running a sale on the new Widget
>   100.
>
> British: The Acme Widgets company are running a sale on the new Widget
>   100.

Comment: In BrE, collective nouns are usually treated *notionally*, taking singular or plural agreement depending on how the speaker is thinking of them rather than based on their grammatical form.  So you'll find that they do not always take plural agreement, even in BrE, although in many cases plural would be the normal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes people might say "India are at 233 at the end of the second day", but in this case, the subject is not a country name (which can be taken as collective in some cases), but "his country", so singular is appropriate.

I think most native listeners would hear "his country were beaten" as jarring, and incorrect. It sounds incorrect to my ear, despite the fact that "India are at 233" etc. sounds fine.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are an Indian. If so, I'll try explaining this by taking cricket's example.

When we talk about the *team* that comprise 11 Indian players, we generally put the plural verb *are*.

So,

> India ***are*** on 233 at the end of the day.

In sports, mentioning country with plural verb is quite common. That said, *"....after his country **were** beaten..."* is fine.

Comment: Of course I'm an Indian. But AFAIK collective nouns take singular verb form and also it sounds better than plural version... don't you think?

Comment: *certainly* but that's how it is. The practice is quite recent I guess. I don't remember *India **are** on X run* as a kid. And, I've grown up watching the game. :)

Comment: I don't know where IE speakers in general stand on this issue, but the primary distinction is that *Americans* tend to stick with the strictly "word-based" position (it's ***a*** country, so it takes a singular verb form). Brits are more inclined to take the semantics into account (since there are ***many*** people in a country, sports team, family, etc., it's not unreasonable to use a plural verb form). But either way it's established idiomatic preference, not a matter of correct/incorrect grammar as such.